# Measuring distance based on time

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, time, millis

I have written a arduino sketch which is used to measure the distance travelled. Since `distance = speed * time` , I have initiated speed = 6. I have initiated `time = millis()` variable and it calculates the time in millis().

So, `distance` is calculated as `(speed*time) /1000` and we get distance for every second.

Now, as soon as the `distance==20`, I want to print `distance` and then delay for 5 seconds. So, as soon as `distance==20` implies `time = 4000` . If I delay for 5 seconds, time becomes 9000. But I want time to start from 4000 itself. So I have initiated another variable called `curTime = time - prevTime`.At the start, `prevTime = 0`. Code:

```
int prevTime = 0;
void loop(){
  unsigned long time = millis();
  unsigned long curTime = time - prevTime;
  int speed = 6;
  unsigned long distance = (speed * curTime)/1000; 
  Serial.println(distance); // displays values of distance 
  if(distance == 20){
    Serial.println(distance);
    delay(5000);
    prevTime = time; 
  }
}
```

So `prevTime = 4000` if distance == 20.
After this, time will be equal to 9000 and curTime will be 9000-4000 which equal 5000. So the distance will be 30 skipping all the values between 20 and 30. I don't want the distance to skip the values between 20 and 30. I have tried a lot but couldn't achieve it. Please help me fix this.

Thanks.

Link for code:

https://circuits.io/circuits/5260912-the-unnamed-circuit/edit

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Thanks for the reply. Please see the link on how code works.When `distance == 20`==> `prevTime=time` ==> `prevTime=4000`(After delay). Now when `curTime` is calculated, it's coming as 5000 (since time=9000 and prevTime=4000). But when I keep `prevTime = millis()`, curTime is started from 0 again. For my output , as soon as `distance==20`, after the delay, again the distance should get calculated from 21, but in the above code, the distance is skipped to 30.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it earlier, but it didn't work.

Comment: This program is not measuring anything. As it stands, it is completely useless, and unlikely to be what you want. Could you please explain clearly what you _actually_ want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `distance == 20` you pause for 5 secs. So all calculations after that will be off by 5 secs. So, `prevTime` should equal 5000.

```
unsigned long time = millis();
unsigned long curTime = time - prevTime;    // 0 or 5000
int speed = 6;
unsigned long distance = (speed * curTime) / 1000; // calculating distance in meters for every milli second
Serial.println(distance);
// Only pause once
if (distance == 20 && prevTime == 0) {
  delay(5000);
  prevTime = 5000;  // Adjust for the delay
}
```